# Elasticsearch multi-match scoring based on the number of matching highlights

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-highlight

I am doing a multi-match search using the following query object using `script_score`:

```
{
    _source: [
        'baseline',
        'cpcr',
        'date',
        'description',
        'dev_status',
        'element',
        'event',
        'id'
    ],
    track_total_hits: true,
    query: {
       script_score: {
           query: {
               bool: {
                   filter: []
               },
           },
           script: {
               source: "def v=doc['description'].value; def score = 10000; score += v.length(); score -= " + "\"" + searchObject.query + "\"" + ".indexOf(v)*50;", // throws error
               params: { highlights: 3 }
           }
       }
    },
    highlight: { fields: { '*': {} } },
    sort: [],
    from: 0,
    size: 50
}
```

I'd like the results to be ordered by their number of highlight matches. For instance the first record would have 5 *< em >*'s, second record would have 4 *< em >* matches and so on. Currently my results aren't sorted this way.

**elasticsearch.config.ts**

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "search_synonyms": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "graph_synonyms",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ],
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
            },
            "narrative": {
                "type":"object",
                "properties":{
                    "_all":{
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

[Sample data](https://pastebin.com/CJzQ5ZmV)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.

When you think about it, since you're using `multi_match`, the docs w/ the most field matches would probably score highest which increases the chances that they would also have the most `<em>`s. It'd still be possible to post-process the `hits` and sort by the num. of occurrences.

The reason it's not possible is because the [highligting mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-highlighting.html#highlighter-internal-work) works outside of the `sort` API and one cannot reach the other. One can always 'hack' it with some fancy script but there's [no straightforward way](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26612#issuecomment-329181677) to do it.

---

Addendum

Check out this related answer to access multiple fields within a script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620705/8160318

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the document score based on the number of highlights/matching occurrences?

Comment: I tried using a script_score to provide a custom score for each document but I don't know how to access multiple fields within `"source"` object (since I use a `multi_match` and search within multiple fields). Please check my updated question.

Comment: You'll need to set `fielddata:true` on your text fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156296/8160318 Or use the `keyword` datatype -- but those are case-sensitive so you'll need to adjust your script to take care of that.

Comment: Thanks, the `fielddata:true` option seems to work. However I'm still not sure how do I search within multiple fields for matching occurrences? In the question above I'm only using description field `doc['description'].value`

Comment: Seems like I can access field data using `doc[key].value` inside `for loop` but throws error when using `doc[key + 'keyword'].value`. Also it seems `fielddata:true` doesn't work for the `narrative` object from the above mapping

Comment: use `doc[key + '.keyword'].value` (dot before `keyword`). Also, all your `.keyword` fields must be defined as such in your mapping. Consider dropping the index & reindexing.